# Binding click event to a input element

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am trying to serve html files from server **without using template engines**. Please find the below script for starting the server.

```
// script.js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
   res.set("Content-Type", "text/html");
   const f = require("./templates")();
   console.log(f);
   res.send(f);
});

app.listen(3103, () => console.log("hi"));

// template.js
const fs = require("fs");
const html = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/temp.html", "utf8");

module.exports = (variables) => {
   return html;
};
```

Following is my html file:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=<device-width>, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="./script.js"></script> <!-- The click function was served in a different file -->
</head>
<body>
    <p>Home Page</p>

    <input type="button" value="Click Me" id="btn" onclick="click()">
    <script>

        console.log("hi");
        function click(){ console.log("_Button clicked"); }                
        //document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
            //console.log("Button Clicked");
        //});

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried the following without any success:

- I included the `click()` inline in the button element, and the function was declared in script tag in the same html file. This did not work.
- I included the fromScript function in `script.js` file and served that file as static content. This did not work as expected.

Then I used addEventListener to bind the click event to input element. Now whenever I click the button, "Button Clicked" message is printed twice.

What is the correct/best practice for binding dom events to the elements?

**Edit**

Thanks for the answer **Thijs Kramer**. But the problem is due to the function name.

If I name the function as **click** it is not working. But if I rename it to **fromScript** it is working.

Should we not use "click" for function name?

Comment: Your `fromScript()` function is defined inside another function, so it's not available in the global scope.

Comment: I did, for your untruthful claim not having asked for best practices as a comment on @Thijs Kramer's answer.

Comment: @connexo: Ok. I thought that he was trying to help me with the issue(click event not working). Thanks for pointing this out. I will be more concise in future whenever I post any question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your naming problem is that the `HTMLElement` API (which all html elements inherit from) has a `click` property. It is a `function` meant to be used to programmatically trigger a click event on the element.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

To avoid confusion and unpredictable behaviour, always make sure to name your variables and functions unambigously with regard to inherited and built-in properties from the prototype chain.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with express :) 
The best practice for binding click events is for example the following:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=<device-width>, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Home Page</p>

    <input type="button" value="Click Me" id="btn">
    <script>
        const button = document.getElementById("btn");
        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            console.log("Button Clicked");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**: I think I know what you mean:

If you rename the function `fromScript` to `click`, you obviously have to change the value of the `onclick` attribute as well:

`<input type="button" onclick="click()" />`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my question. Please check the Edit section. I have not asked for the best practice. The issue here is why the click event is not working.

Comment: You literally wrote "What is the correct/best practice for binding dom events to the elements?" so I've provided you with the best practice.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. Please run this example in your browser. https://jsbin.com/buzudepise/edit?html,js,output. I tried this in windows -> chrome & macOS -> chrome. If it is working please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work fine:

```
// script.js
const express = require("express");
// const bodyParser = require("body-parser"); 
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.listen(3103, () => console.log("hi"));
```

then `node script.js` and try to access it by going to `http://localhost:3103/temp.html`
?